# SQL to remove time overlaps between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, overlap

I have two tables. Each table has two fields: `from_date` and `to_date`. I need to find all the records in `table A` that do not overlap records in `table B`.

I am using MSSQL 2008.

```
CREATE TABLE Table_A(from_date datetime , to_date datetime )

CREATE TABLE Table_B(from_date datetime , to_date datetime )

Insert into Table_A (from_date, to_date) values ('2016-09-01 10:00:00','2016-09-01 11:00:00')

Insert into Table_A (from_date, to_date) values ('2016-09-01 11:00:00','2016-09-01 12:00:00')

Insert into Table_A (from_date, to_date) values ('2016-09-01 12:00:00','2016-09-01 13:00:00')

Insert into Table_B (from_date, to_date) values ('2016-09-01 10:00:00','2016-09-01 12:00:00')

Insert into Table_B (from_date, to_date) values ('2016-09-01 13:00:00','2016-09-01 14:00:00')

Insert into Table_B (from_date, to_date) values ('2016-09-01 14:00:00','2016-09-01 15:00:00')
```

The result should be only the third record in Table A (1200-1300) because it does not overlap any record in Table B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want no overlaps, then here is one way:

```
select a.*
from table_a a
where not exists (select 1
                  from table_b b
                  where a.from_date < b.to_date and a.to_date > b.from_date
                 );
```

Comment: Alias for table_b is missed.